# Node js - Reading .json with underscore?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

The .json file is like

```
"person":{"_info":{"name":"john","age":17}}
```

In my node, if i run `console.log(person.body);` it prints out fine, but if I try `console.log(person._info.body);` or `console.log(person._info);` it returns undefined.

So is there a way that I can print out the `._info`?

Thanks

Comment: that doesn't look like valid json. a [mcve] would help

Comment: @DanielA.White [{"_index":"staging","_type":"profile","_id":"56361ee8dc618fec00512641","_score":0.29108974,"_source":{"baseCountry":"ghana","displayName":"With One Of Each","sector":"Information technology","_kind":"comapany"}}] ... I would like to print the displayName

Comment: @RobGeraghty — Don't just paste more JSON into a comment. Edit the question. Your MVCE should show how you try to read it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your json isn't valid, this code is working :

```js
var obj = {
  "person": {
    "_info": {
      "name":"john",
      "age":17
    }
  }
};

console.log(obj.person._info);
```

Comment: If it wasn't valid then it would error when parsed.